# VSTS Work Item import assigned to TFS group

Tags: excel, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I'm trying to import work items from TFS to VSTS. I have some work items that are assigned to a group that won't import. I recreated the group in VSTS, but when I try to import excel gives me an error:

> The identity value 'TriageGroup' for field 'AssignedTo' is an unknown identity.

Triage group is not an AD group which is why VSTS can't assign to it, but it never was in the old TFS world either. Any ideas? Is it possible to import WIs assigned to a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be some customization made for the WIT Definition in your TFS server what allow the group to be assigned for Work Items. But for VSTS, there isn't any way to  customize the WIT definition for now. That means you cannot assign the work item to group in VSTS. You can only assign the work item to an valid user.